# i want to hide material ui buttons

Tags: reactjs, menu

i want the material ui menu item button to be hidden in full screen but show only in mobile screen. i tried method like below:

```
<Button  className="menu__button" aria-controls="simple-menu" aria-haspopup="true" onClick={handleClick}>
        Open Menu
      </Button>
      <Menu
     className="menu__button"
        id="simple-menu"
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        keepMounted
        open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
        onClose={handleClose}
      >
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Login</MenuItem>
```

css for this is :

```
.menu__button {
display: none;
}
```

but its not working. anyone help?

Comment: can you inspect element of the menu and see if it has the menu__button class?

Comment: i did earlier and added the muibutton-label but didnot work. as it was for label pnly. re inspected again properly and added the proper class and worked. thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: If you got it fixed, you can post the answer for others, mark it completed, or close this question.

Comment: Could it be that this property is being overwritten?
Please check the button in the inspector for that class and CSS property.
If "display" is overwritten by a MUI class use an CSS-id. You should do that nonetheless because it is a single button you wan to hide, not a group of buttons.

If not you can always overwritte the MUI-classes in your CSS like so:
```
.MUI-button{...}
```
And please use the proper naming convention for CSS like menu-button

Comment: yeah its class is .MuiButtonBase-root.MuiButton-root.MuiButton-text i added css to it and hide it.